# How an image in Asset of Xcode is being changed by itself?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9

The image 1 is the screenshot of the app while image 2 is the original image. The original image is in the Asset file of Xcode. As you can see, the design in the image is appearing differently than the original image. I have researched about it, it seems as the compression on Xcode is making the change, but how a compression can change the image this way? I have selected "Render As" - "Original image" and "Compression" - "Lossless" in the image asset but it didn't help.

[image: Original image[![][1]]

[image]

Comment: Your second screenshot shows nothing.  Can't figure what you are asking.

Comment: I think the OP means that the background image is slightly zoomed in/squashed when in position in the app

Comment: @Hem adjust your imageView contentMode. try aspect fill/aspect fit

Comment: @Scriptable yes the OP is the one with curved lines. In the app, its being altered. I tried changing to aspect fill/ fit, didn't help :/

Comment: You need to make it more clear that the image is being stretched, but that is not the problem.  The problem is that while it is being stretched, the curves in some of the lines are turning into straight lines with sharp angles instead of a smooth curve.  What is the image recolution of the image you are saving?  What type of file is it?  Is it a vector graphic?  PNG?  I would try saving it as a PNG, in a resolution that is equal to or greater than the display on a retina iOS device.

Comment: To make the changes clear, in your first image, draw an arrow to some of the sharp angular lines that are smooth in the original.

Comment: As that image not change but the image-view contenet mode are different setting for both view. Make sure you setting a right content-mode for each and check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have issue with the  image view stretching property. 
Set the stretching value to default. That is

X: 0 Y: 0
Width: 1 Height: 1

[image: You can see the screenshot and let me know if it works]

Comment: thanks it solved my problem, so the problem was with stretching not with compression.

Answer (score 1):

The imageView in the top image you've shown is a different aspect-ratio than the bottom image (your actual image):

```
Top:     748 x 640
Bottom:  690 x 798
```

You have to decide how you want that handled. If you changed it to aspect fit or fill, it *must* have looked different from what you posted - although may not have given you exactly what you want.

In this screen-cap, all three image views are `200 x 231` - which matches the ratio of the image view in your top image:

[image]

The left one is set to `Fill`, the center is set to `Aspect Fit` and the right one is `AspectFill`. I set the corner radius, and also the border (the red line) to show how the Content Mode affects the displayed image.

`Aspect Fill` is *probably* what you want... When the image view is "tall and narrow" (as you have it currently) it will **fill** top-to-bottom and clip the sides. If your image view ends up being "short and wide" it will **fill** left-to-right and clip the top and bottom.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I am using Aspect Fit in the card. I have tested with Fill, fit and every changes their but it couldn't help to solve the sharp bend that's happening in the curved lines.